# Multiplication resulting in zero

Tags: c

The following loop should recursively multiply a value by itself starting with 2. After some iterations the value seems to be 0 instead of ever growing numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 2; ; i = i * i) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain me why? Is there some way to fix it?

Comment: It's impossible to suggest how you can fix this, since there's no way of telling what you were trying to do in the first place.

Comment: Hmmm: OP, user user6007887, gone/deleted after only 20 minutes.  Looks like HW question was answered.

Comment: Well, though OP is gone, [what's wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319596/where-is-the-op-of-this-question#comment326213_319597) with this question that it is downvoted so badly?

Comment: By the edit history it looks like it was more ambiguous originally. Christian has added _"should output exponentiations of 2"_ which improved it a lot.

Answer (score 21):

Plain `int` in C is `signed`. There is no conditional expression in `for` to break the loop. This makes it infinite which results in [signed integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) and which ultimately invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In this case you can't expect any good.

Answer (score 19):

In this case it will very quickly reach zero if it overflows (assuming the way overflows are handled is very basic). Look at the operation in binary:

```
C  Bits
0  00000010
0  00000100
0  00010000
1  00000000
```

So you see that for an 8 bit integer, the overflow leaves you with zero (rather than some other number, or -128 as you'd get with signed integers).

In 5 iterations exactly the same thing will happen to a 32 bit integer.

Comment: As far as I know `signed` overflow is undefined behavior. Could you please provide a confirmation from standard that says about it can reaches to `0`?

Comment: @haccks hence having to add "assuming the way overflows are handled is very basic". In the C standard the example given for [underfined behaviour](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p3) is integer overflow. Unsigned overflow does not exist as unsigned integers are always truncated. So no, but for the common case that signed integers are stored as 2s complement, with ALU treating them as unsigned integers, the result will be as described.

Comment: If that's the case then it must be "implementation defined" instead of "undefined", but it's not.